# How to handle "Limited time only" in-app purchases on Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I want to create some in-app purchases that are available for a limited time only. For example, I want my app to display a product for sale from March-April.

My concern is for the users who buy the product in that time frame. Will they be able to "restore" their purchase after I remove it from sale in  April?

I want users who have purchased the product to be able to see it when they launch their app and have access to it if they get a new device or uninstall and reinstall my app.

Comment: If they are non-consumable purchases, then yes, once the user has purchased that item they own it forever and can restore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a very standard behavior across iOS to have a Restore Purchases button in your app. Checkout StoreKit's method: `func restoreCompletedTransactions()`. This function should return the product they purchased even if you remove it from sale.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions